# Does Ios allows a user registeration to web page from a app in in-app browser

Tags: ios, react-native, appstore-approval, inappbrowser

I have created a ios app in react-native and this app rely on a parent app for registeration and login authentication. Previously, when user clicks the register button in app, we direct the user to a parent app for registeration. But appStore doesn't allows to navigate and rejects the app. 
      So, if I created a registeration page in website and when user clicks the register link can I re direct them to a web page with a in-app browser in react- native and does appstore allows it?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is no , I have faced similar issue where we have re-directed user to webview for registration and it got rejected , You can try with in-app-browser that will open a with in app , But I will lead you to lot of issue about after registration user need to close the browser manually , saving local preference data . My suggestion is to implement the native screen for registration .

Comment: My registeration page is generalised for both parent and child app. So can I host a registeration page in my website and redirect the user to the web page for registeration through in-app browser and give a success message and intimate user to "exit the browser after the completion of registeration"?

Comment: u can give a try not issue , But apple won't prefer webview registration , But some time it will get success approval